# Notepad ++change specific value ;12; into ;8; based on list of search values

Tags: notepad++

I have a file that contains multiple columns.
1 column with the value ;12; i have to change to ;8; based on a list of values that i have in a seperate file. The values in te seperate file are also in the file that i have to change.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Kind regards,

Peter

[Bit of the original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKeqK.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXRUt.png)

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71140738/edit) and add sample text and expected result as well as what you have tried.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).